# How do I schedule an AWS Lambda cron to run at 11:30pm on the last day of the month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'd like my Lambda function to run on the last day of every month at 11:30pm.

I'm using the Serverless Framework so all I need is the right Schedule Expression ([docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) & [info here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html))

Any help greatly appreciated.

NB: Unfortunately I can't just do it at the start of the month as there's a dependency on pulling data from a 3rd party tool that only calculates data for 'this month'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html):

> - The **L** wildcard in the Day-of-month or Day-of-week fields specifies the last day of the month or week.

So, try this cron expression for 11:30 PM at the last day of the month:

```
cron(30 23 L * ? *)
```

Comment: After figuring this out I got stuck on the timezone issue but ended up opening up the cloudwatch rule itself and figured out the cron is based on GMT.